# Storyboard won't open in Xamarin (Visual studio)

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm using Visual studio (PC) with Xamarin to build a IOS application.
Xamarin stopped opening my storyboard after some modifications, I receive [these messages](https://justpaste.it/6c1r7).

The storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14113" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="6042">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="5041">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ecranchargement" id="5042" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="5039"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="5040"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5043">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="logo.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5046">
                                <rect key="frame" x="56.5" y="299" width="262.5" height="87.5"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5046" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="3" id="5051"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Chargement..." textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5052">
                                <rect key="frame" x="141.5" y="376.5" width="92" height="17"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.11372549019607843" green="0.16470588235294117" blue="0.24705882352941178" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <color key="tintColor" red="0.85490196078431369" green="0.90588235294117647" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="5046" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="5043" secondAttribute="centerX" id="5048"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5046" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="5043" secondAttribute="centerY" constant="9" id="5049"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5046" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5043" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.7" id="5050"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5052" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="5043" secondAttribute="centerX" id="5053"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="5052" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="5046" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-10" id="5054"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5044" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1799" y="369"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Webviewcontroller-->
        <scene sceneID="5289">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="webview" id="5290" customClass="webviewcontroller" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="5287"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="5288"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5291">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5292" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1306" y="372"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Login-->
        <scene sceneID="6041">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="6042" customClass="login" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="6039"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="6040"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="6043">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="fond.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6426">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                            </imageView>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="logo.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6046">
                                <rect key="frame" x="38" y="70" width="300" height="100"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6046" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="3" id="6049"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Adresse email:" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6052">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="220" width="375" height="21"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="6056"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.16862745098039217" green="0.18431372549019609" blue="0.22352941176470589" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6057">
                                <rect key="frame" x="38" y="251" width="300" height="30"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="6060"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.18823529411764706" green="0.22745098039215686" blue="0.28235294117647058" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" returnKeyType="done" textContentType="email"/>
                            </textField>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Mot de passe:" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6072">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="301" width="375" height="21"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="6073"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="6082"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.16862745098039217" green="0.18431372549019609" blue="0.22352941176470589" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6074">
                                <rect key="frame" x="38" y="332" width="300" height="30"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="6075"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.18823529411764706" green="0.22745098039215686" blue="0.28235294117647058" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocorrectionType="no" returnKeyType="done" secureTextEntry="YES" textContentType="password"/>
                            </textField>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6127">
                                <rect key="frame" x="38" y="412" width="300" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.19607843137254902" green="0.20000000000000001" blue="0.22352941176470589" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="6131"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <state key="normal" title="Se connecter">
                                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                            <view opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6440">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="539" width="375" height="128"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Mot de passe oublié ?" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6446">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="29" width="375" height="21"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="6449"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" red="0.23529411764705882" green="0.27450980392156865" blue="0.35294117647058826" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Inscription" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6452">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="66" width="375" height="21"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="6456"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" red="0.23529411764705882" green="0.27450980392156865" blue="0.35294117647058826" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="0.50196078431372548" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="6443"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6447"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="top" constant="29" id="6448"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="width" id="6450"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="width" id="6455"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6457"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6040" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6452" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="41" id="6459"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6446" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="sIF-gR-9c4"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6046" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6047"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6046" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.8" id="6048"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6046" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6039" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="50" id="6051"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6052" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" id="6053"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6052" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6054"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6052" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6046" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="900" constant="50" id="6055"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6057" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6052" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="6058"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6057" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.8" id="6059"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6057" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6061"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6072" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6057" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="6079"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6072" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6081"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6072" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" id="6083"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6074" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6072" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="6084"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6057" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6074" secondAttribute="trailing" id="6090"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6057" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6074" secondAttribute="leading" id="6091"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6127" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.8" id="6128"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6127" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6129"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6127" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6074" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="50" id="6130"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6426" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="height" id="6434"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6426" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="width" id="6435"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6426" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6436"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6426" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="6043" secondAttribute="centerY" id="6439"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6440" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6426" secondAttribute="width" id="6442"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6426" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="bottom" id="6444"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6440" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6426" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6445"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="connexion" destination="6127" id="name-outlet-6127"/>
                        <outlet property="email" destination="6057" id="name-outlet-6057"/>
                        <outlet property="passe" destination="6074" id="name-outlet-6074"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="6044" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="735" y="377"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="fond.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <image name="logo.png" width="300" height="100"/>
    </resources>
    <color key="tintColor" red="0.85490196078431369" green="0.90588235294117647" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
</document>
```

I tried to clean the solution, restart the pc, the mac and the iphone, but I still can't open my storyboard.

I have the same problem if I try to open the storyboard in VS mac.

Comment: did you try open it with Xcode ?

Comment: yes it opened and it says it repaired some inconstancies, I saved but it's still the same in visual studio...

Comment: that means it has to do with the modifications you made, try removing/reverting on Storyboard / Xcode , and try re-adding everything. we need to see code to help you more

Comment: I added the storyboard to my post

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

1. > Right click your project -> Unload Project
2. > Right click your project again -> Reload Project

Comment: Try to delete the connection with your Mac and connect again.

Comment: Make sure that the version of the VS and Xcode are up to date

Answer (score 0):

I removed these constraints:

```
<constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="6443"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6447"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="top" constant="29" id="6448"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6446" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="width" id="6450"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="width" id="6455"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6440" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6457"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6040" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6452" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="41" id="6459"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="6452" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6446" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="sIF-gR-9c4"/>
```

And have been able to open the storyboard. I don't know what was the problem...